# Dealing with non-public classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

Non-public top-level (i.e., package-private) classes in Java do not require the file name to match (e.g., class Foo may be defined in Bar.java). I don't think such a feature is of any use any more (since nested classes were introduced many years ago).

Sometimes it leads to problems: After some refactorings I ended with file names not matching their class names, which confused me (while committing) and also Eclipse (some files weren't recompiled although they had to).

Is there a way how to forbid such classes in Eclipse?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Are you saying Eclipse does not compile package-protected classes if the class name differs from the file name?

Comment: I'm using 3.7.0, but the recompiling problem mentioned happened some time ago (and I can't reproduce it). Since then I've avoided non-public classes, but now I want to use them again, as often as possible.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the compile problem either. However I don't know how to get eclipse to validate file name for non-public classes. I do not know personally of any way to do this however. The few error/warning settings are under `window > preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings` however nothing there that can solve your problem. I think it's probably because Eclipse can't tell whether this is an inner class or not. Would making the classes public but all the methods non-public (including the constructors) help?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), which also has a very nice plugin for Eclipse, [eclipse-cs](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/).  In the eclipse-cs configuration for a given check configuration, under Miscellaneous, there is a check for "Outer Type File Name" that can be enabled, with a description of "Checks that the outer type name and the file name match. For example, the class Foo must be in a file named Foo.java.".

In order to truly "forbid such classes", this check can even be set to have an "error" severity (which by default, will prevent a build, at least in Eclipse) - instead of the default "warning" severity.

As an added bonus, using Checkstyle doesn't lock you in to running this check within Eclipse.  Checkstyle is easily integrated into various build tools such as Apache Maven, allowing this issue to be checked for even if you or another user weren't using Eclipse.

Comment: I tried it... but I wasn't happy with the plugin at all. It checks everything what eclipse does, so I get each warning twice. It has millions of checks, all of them on by default, and no way to switch them off globally. It made my eclipse slow like hell....

Comment: When's the last time you tried it?  There is certainly a way to switch of checks globally, or even to enable/disable Checkstyle per-project, or to have specific check configurations per-project.  You could even check for just this one issue, if you'd like.

Comment: Maybe one week ago? I've learned about it from your answer. Indeed, I was looking for a way to switch off all warnings and enabling only the one, but found no way except for clicking on all checkboxes but one. The slow-down of my eclipse made me unwilling to do anything with it. Maybe it interacts badly with Lombok, or whatever. Maybe I'll give it another try after some re-install.